# Server to Server Auth with Google Apps scripts API executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm trying to set up a Google apps script API executable with Server to server auth for a Python micro-service I'm setting up.

Using the Quickstart, I was able to make it work via Auth2, but I was unable to make it work with a service account. I gave access to script and spreadsheet to service account email. Project ID in client secret JSON matches the project ID of the app scripts. I deployed it as an API executable just the same.

This is my code below (although I don't think the code is the issue):

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
service = build('script', 'v1', http=http_auth)


request = {'function': 'testApi'}
response = service.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId='SCRIPT_ID').execute()

print(response)
```

The testApi function in my App Script is a simple function that returns "It works".

I keep getting that the user does not have permission (403) when using personal account, or even 500 when using organization (G Suite account).

As mentioned earlier, the Quickstart tutorial from Google documentation worked, but this is not using a service account.

Has anyone made Google Apps Scripts API executable working with a server to server auth account flow?

Comment: Does you service account have API client access in the admin console? (Security > Advanced Settings > Manage API client access) If not, you'll need to add your project's service account credentials & grant it access to the appropriate scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check this tutorial about [Using Google Service Accounts with Google Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script). This sample code shows how to use OAuth in Google Apps Script using [Service Accounts](https://ctrlq.org/code/20364-google-service-accounts-introduction).

For this code to work, you need to [create a Google Service account](https://ctrlq.org/code/20365-create-google-service-accounts) with [domain-wide delegation](https://ctrlq.org/code/20371-service-account-domain-wide-delegation), substitute the private key and client client email with the actual values and also add the Client Id to your Google Apps admin console with the Drive API Scope. The OAuth 2.0 access tokens are stored in the Script Properties.

```
var JSON = {
    "private_key": "Your Private Key",
    "client_email": "serviceacount@project-ctrlq.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1234567890",
    "user_email": "amit@labnol.org"
};

function getOAuthService(user) {
    return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
        .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
        .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
        .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
        .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}

function getUserFiles() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?pageSize=1';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            }
        });
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
}

function reset() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
}
```

Also, if you are getting the 403 Insufficient permission error, it is likely because the application is requesting access to API scopes that are not authorized in the Google Apps admin console. The `invalid_grant` error is likely due to incorrect date and time settings of the server that is hosting the application.